# How not to propagate dired-actual-switches as a directory variable to the sub directories

Tags: dired, directory-local-variables, local-variables, association-lists

I want to set `dired-actual-switches` for the directory `/path/to/data`, but *not* for `data`'s subdirectories. So I generated the following `.dir-locals.el` file in `/path/to/data`:

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((dired-mode .
  ((dired-actual-switches . "-laht")
   (subdirs . nil))))
```

And as I hope for, when I call dired on the directory `/path/to/data` it is listed by date. However when I open a dired buffer for `/path/to/data/sub` the directory listing for `sub` is in date order as well - despite the `subdirs . nil` entry in `.dir-locals.el`.

How do I achieve that `dired-actual-switches` is only set for the directory the `.dir-locals.el` file sits in?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the `subdirs` behaviour is tied to `buffer-file-name` (which isn't populated in dired buffers).

Comment: So it's kind of a bug?

Comment: Well my guess was wrong -- `dired-mode` calls `hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer` which is based on `default-directory` which *is* set. That's not to say there *isn't* a bug, though. I'm not going to dig into it right now, but if it's a reliably repeatable issue then you can `M-x report-emacs-bug` with a recipe starting from running `emacs -Q`

Comment: What @phils said. If you can repeat it starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` then please consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @phils Have tried it with a vanilla `emacs -Q` and then it behaves correctly!!! So it must be something with my setup...

Comment: @phils Actually my last comment was not correct: Vanilla Emacs does the wrong thing too, I just didn't notice, because *the first time* I visit the directory with the `.dir-locals.el`file (or the subdir for that matter) the variables in the file do not get applied, but subsequently when creating the dired buffer again they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this seems to be a bug in GNU Emacs 25.2.1.

The `dired-actual-switches` setting in `.dir-locals.el` is applied to a sub directory under the directory with the `.dir-locals.el` file.

Furthermore the application of the directory variable seem to happen *after* the dired buffer is created for the first time in an emacs session. This means when you create the dired buffer with the directory for the first time the variable is not applied whatsoever and when you create the buffer again it is applied - in both cases: the directory and sub directory.

I'm filing a bug report.